# How can I create Associative array in Swift 3

Tags: php, arrays, swift3

Hi I am very new to Swift and am trying to use array.

I want to create an array in swift3 similar to this PHP array as below:

```
$countries = array(
                   "UK"=>array(
                          "gold_medal" => 59,
                          "prime_minister" => 'XYZ'
                              ),
                    "Germany"=>array(
                          "gold_medal" => 17,
                          "prime_minister" => 'abc'
                              ),
                  )
```

In the array above the country name are dynamic variables.

Comment: you mean a `dictionary`!?

Comment: I don't know luk, If that is the best solution then why not. But I don't know how to use it.

Comment: you should start reading a bit about swift https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

These are called dictionaries in Swift, and you can create one like this:

```
let countries: [String: Any] = [
        "UK": ["gold_medal": 59, "prime_minister": "xyz"],
        "Germany": ["gold_medal": 17, "prime_minister": "abc"]
    ]
```

EDIT: Swift is great at inferring the variable type from the value that is being assigned, which is why we can write

```
let count = 5
```

and the compiler will figure out that `count` is of type `Int`. However, with the dictionary example above, Xcode (8.2.1) throws a warning *heterogenous collection literal could only be inferred to '[String : Any]'; add explicit type annotation if this is intentional*, which is why the example includes the type `[String: Any]`.

More about dictionaries in [The Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html)

Answer (score 5):

You need to use dictionary with dictionaries as values:

```
let countries = ["UK": ["gold_medal" : 59,
                        "prime_minister" : "XYS"],
                 "Germany": ["gold_medal" : 17,
                        "prime_minister" : "abc"]]
```